# WritePrivateProfileSection writes with extra caracs

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a little problem that is driving me crazy. 
I have std::string that contains some data, which I wanna save in an INI file.

So I did as below:

```
std::string strBuffer;
char line[MAX_BUFFER + 1];

for (int i=0; i < NbrElts; i++)
{
    //Here I get pData filled with data 

    sprintf_s(line, "%s%d=%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", "key", i, pData->sType, pData->sId, pData->sName, pData->sCountry, pData->sSite, pData->sCDB, pData->sShortName);
    strBuffer += line;
}

WritePrivateProfileSection("PERSONAL", strBuffer.c_str(), GetMYFile());
```

so at this point, when I use debugger the content of my strBuffer is good, but when the `WritePrivateProfileSection` is executed I have extra caracters written into my file.

I tried to use conversion before writing in the INI file but with no success. 
Any help what may be the clue?

Thank you.

---

Example :

strBuffer contains `"HELLO WORLD"` and in my file I get `HELLO WORLD נננ`

> PS: Besides that I missed to add "\0" after each key, the main problem comes from using std::string as it doesn't handle the null
>   termination, so even with adding the "\0" I still got the messy output
>   ---> Have to change to char[].

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): _The data in the buffer pointed to by the lpString parameter consists of one or more null-terminated strings, followed by a final null character._ So you need 2 null chars at the end.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp So you suggest That I add sthing like strBuffer +="\0\0"; ??

Comment: It's been a while since I used ini files, but it looks like you need `\0` after each entry, and then another `\0` after the last one.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: thx it works !!

Comment: strBuffer +="\0\0"; is triple null terminated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.c_str()` is already null-terminated, let's represent this as

```
{ 'H', 'i', '\0' };
```

WritePrivateProfileSection expects multiple strings, separated by a single `'\0'`, terminated by `'\0\0'`, e.g. for the two entries `x=1` and `y=2`

```
{ 'x', '=', '1', '\0', 'y', '=', '2', '\0', '\0' }
```

---

The problem with your code is

```
s += line;
```

which expects a zero-terminated string on the rhs. You could use:

```
int len = sprintf(buffer, "%s=%d\0", key, value); // TODO! Check for error!
s += std::string(line, len); // don't stop at the first '\0'!
```

but at this point I'd use a `std::vector<char>` instead, since the std::string behavior seems too error-prone here, and we rely on the finer details of what constitutes a string.